# React очистить fileRejections в ReactDropzone

Tags: reactjs

Пишу на реакте, использую ReactDropzone from 'react-dropzone', там есть такие поля  {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, fileRejections }) => {... я использую fileRejections чтобы определить есть ли ошибки с файлами, допустим я добавил два не правильных файла (другой формат или объем), у меня появляется алерт с предупрждением и названиями некоректных файлом, дальше я нажимаю на крестик и хочу чтобы этот алерт пропал, а он зависит от fileRejections, так вот можно ли как-то очистить этот fileRejections ?

```
  <ReactDropzone
    disabled={extraFiles > 0}
    onDrop={processOnDrop}
    minSize={minSize}
    maxSize={maxSize}
    accept={
      customAllowedExtensions
        ? customAllowedExtensions.map(ext => `.${ext}`).join(',')
        : allowedExtensions &&
          allowedExtensions.map(ext => `.${ext}`).join(',')
    }
  >
    {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, fileRejections }) => {
      let rejectionsFiles = fileRejections;
      console.log('fileRejections');
      return (
        <div onClick={() => setDropPressed(true)}>
          <div {...getRootProps()}>
            <input name="file" {...getInputProps()} />
            <BoxStyled className="text-center">
              <div>
                <DropzoneTextStyled
                  typography="caption"
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: intl.get('UPLOAD_FILES_MUI', {
                      extensions: extensionText,
                    }),
                  }}
                />
              </div>

              <ButtonStyled size="small" startIcon={<FileUploadIcon />}>
                {intl.get('SELECT_FILES')}
              </ButtonStyled>
            </BoxStyled>
          </div>
          {rejectionsFiles.length > 0 && (
            <DropzoneErrorAlert
              clearRejectionsFiles={() => {
                console.log('clear');
              }}
              fileRejections={rejectionsFiles}
            />
          )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напрямую изменить не сможете - туда попадают файлы не прошедшие по ограничениям. Однако эти файлы так же и не попадают в основной список.

Поэтому состав особой роли не играет и можно лишь поверхностно проверять его заполнение. Т.е. создать новое состояние и по событию в компоненте `onDropRejected`, а так же по клику на кнопку закрытия менять его. Так же при необходимости изменить состояние при срабатывании onDrop. Сам же попап с ошибкой отображать в зависимости от этого состояния, а не `fileRejections`.

Т.е. где-нибудь выше компонента

```
const [reject, setReject] = useState(false);
```

В самом компоненте

```
<Dropzone
  onDropRejected={() => setReject(true)}
  onDrop={processOnDrop}>
```

В модалке:

```
{reject && (
  <DropzoneErrorAlert
    clearRejectionsFiles={() => setReject(false)}
    fileRejections={rejectionsFiles}
  />
)}
```

Comment: я тоже так подумал, что fileRejections нельзя очищать и тоже пробовал со стейтом, это логично, но я возможно не использовал onDropRejected поэтому ничего не работало, спасибо что подсказал, теперь прям все отлично, большое спасибо!